# sentence from chibimakuro :) ベタに真珠っていう諺をきくと

Tags: manga

was translating chibimakuro and there is this sentence:
ベタに真珠っていう諺をきくと

its ends with と, there is 諺(proverb) kanji, 
from context its easy to say it has  to do with
"cast pearls before swine" saying. but what is really going on here?

i uploaded whole strip:
https://ibb.co/1spfL0D

Comment: In the strip, it's written as「ブタ」rather than「ベタ」

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "what is going on here". Can you be more specific?

Comment: 'Chibimakuro'??

Comment: I'm sure it's Chibi Maruko -- typos or what have you

Answer (score 2):

Part of what might be making it harder for you to understand it fully is that the sentence isn't complete. You need the part on the other side of the panel to complete the sentence.

Therefore, consider the following:

> ブタに真珠っていう諺をきくと、心ときめくブー。

Now, let's parse (adding some markings to help delineate):

> （「ブタに真珠」っていう諺）をきくと、（心ときめく）｛ブー｝

You've correctly identified that ブタに真珠 is the equivalent of "casting pearls before swine" (though for some reason the artist wrote ブタ instead of 豚 -- there might be context behind that somewhere). This is being identified with っていう諺 as "the saying that goes (casting pearls before swine)", loosely speaking. This noun phrase is the section in parentheses.

The noun phrase is being "heard" by the speaker, which is the をきくと, and と here is is an event marker, so, so far we have:

> Whenever I hear the saying "Casting pearls before swine"...

...and I think you can figure out the rest now.